# call class method within a framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

In objective-c how can i call class method inside a framework?

This is the method declaration:

```
public class func setGameLevel(level:Int)
{
    current_level = level
}
```

That is the class declaration (of the framework class):

```
public class MyClass
{
```

I imported the framework, now how can i call the method setGameLevel of the MyClass method?

In swift its called using:

```
MyClass.setGameLevel(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[MyClass setGameLevel:1]
```